# WPF New DataGrid Row Parameter NULL on Button Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

new to WPF here.  This first app I'm building is using a RelayCommand and DataGrid with ButtonCommand to edit or enter a new user.  For a new user with values entered into the open row, the OneditButtonCommand is being called when pressed, but the Item being passed as a parameter is always null.  I tried switching the order of Command and CommandParameter in the XAML to see if the Command was being set before a defined parameter, but the button command object was still NULL.  Does any solution jump out to anyone?  Many thanks in advance!

The ViewModel:

```
public partial class UsersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RelayCommand<UserViewModel> editButton_Click_Command { get; set; }

    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        editButton_Click_Command = new RelayCommand<UserViewModel>(OneditButton_Click_Command);

        this.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>();

        this.Users.Add(new UserViewModel() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", EMail = "JohnDoe@yahoo.com", EndDate = new DateTime(2016,2,1), Position = "Developer", UserID = 0 });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> _Users;
    public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> Users
    {
        get { return _Users; }
        set { _Users = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Users"); }
    }

    private void OneditButton_Click_Command(UserViewModel obj)
    {
        //Parameter object is always NULL here!!!
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="Base_V"
    x:Class="DbEntities.UsersWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DbEntities"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:DbEntities"
    xmlns:staticData="clr-namespace:DbEntities"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="UsersWindow" Height="Auto" Width="900">
    <Window.Resources>
        <staticData:PositionsList x:Key="PositionsList" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:UsersViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.editButton_Click_Command, ElementName=Base_V}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >Edit</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User ID" Binding="{Binding UserID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-Mail" Binding="{Binding EMail}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="Position" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource PositionsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Position}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Date" Binding="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The RelayCommand was taken from here: http://www.kellydun.com/wpf-relaycommand-with-parameter/

**EDIT:**
It was suggested that the UserViewModel be posted to see if the issue can be resolved here or in another question.  There are a couple of test users pulled from a database as well.

UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set { _FirstName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
    }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set { _LastName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName"); }
    }

    private string _EMail;
    public string EMail
    {
        get { return _EMail; }
        set { _EMail = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("EMail"); }
    }

    private int _UserID;
    public int UserID
    {
        get { return _UserID; }
        set { _UserID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("UserID"); }
    }

    private string _Position;
    public string Position
    {
        get { return _Position; }
        set { _Position = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Position"); }
    }

    private DateTime? _EndDate;
    public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get { return _EndDate; }
        set { _EndDate = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("EndDate"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

On the home page:

```
UsersViewModel Usersvm = new UsersViewModel();
Usersvm.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>();
DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
var pulledUsers = db.uspGetNonAdminUsers().ToList();
foreach (var result in pulledUsers)
{
    var pulledUser = new UserViewModel
    {
        FirstName = result.FirstName,
        LastName = result.LastName,
        EMail = result.Email,
        UserID = result.UserID,
        Position = result.Position,
        EndDate = result.EndDate
    };
    Usersvm.Users.Add(pulledUser);
}
new UsersWindow(Usersvm).Show();
```

The UsersWindow:

```
public partial class UsersWindow : Window
{
    public UsersWindow(UsersViewModel uvm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = uvm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the code it looks like it should work, no obvious problems. Try changing the parameter type to `object` and see if you get a different type.

Comment: Thanks @benPearce.  I changed the parameter type on the private void OneditButton_Click_Command to object, and clicking the button now doesn't hit the function.  Was that the correct change?

Comment: not really sure it was just a guess to gather more information, you may also need to change the RelayCommand<> to object as well.

Comment: That's what d.moncada suggested below.  After making the change(s), the object being passed tests as not NULL, the casted ViewModel passed a test as != NULL, and yet any field pulled from there, like LastName, is still NULL.  Does that particularly indicate anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

Update your property to be type `object`:

```
   public RelayCommand<object> editButton_Click_Command { get; set; }
```

update your instantiation to use `object`

```
editButton_Click_Command = new RelayCommand<object>(OneditButton_Click_Command);
```

then, update your event handler to have a param `object` and cast accordingly.

```
private void OneditButton_Click_Command(object obj)
{
    var associatedViewModel = obj as UserViewModel;
    if (associatedViewModel != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @d.moncada.  The changes have been made, and a test says that neither the original passed obj nor the associatedViewModel is NULL, but then any value retrieved, like LastName, is NULL.  Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, so that solves your first issue (passing a null object to the command). Sounds like you are having other issues w/ DataBinding and your overall UserViewModel. You will need to post code for your UserViewModel class... but I would suggest maybe making a new question, since this issue appears to be unrelated (based on your title)

Comment: Thanks again.  I posted the UserViewModel to see if anything jumps out and whether or not another question would be more appropriate.

Comment: Interesting.. I have copied your code, put a breakpoint on the edit command, and I see 'John' set as the FirstName. Have you tried breaking into it? It appears to work as expected.

Comment: Yes, a breakpoint is set just inside the function.  After the associatedViewModel cast, a new "string lastName = associatedViewModel.LastName;" returns NULL for lastName.  An "if (associatedViewModel == null)" statement indicates the associatedViewModel is not NULL, though.  Any idea what's happening there?  I'm also pulling in a couple of other test users from a database.  I'll update the original question to reflect that detail.

Comment: Discovered the answer to this in the related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608286/wpf-object-not-null-on-check-but-properties-null/36612706#36612706